# Python: how to pass over files when copying

Tags: python, permissions, copy

I am copying directories, but I'm running into an issue where my script throws the error that it doesn't have permissions to access a certain file. I know there is a way to check the access of files using os.access, but I'm not entirely sure how I can just skip over files I don't have rw access on and continue to copy what I can.

Edit: Specifically, I'm trying to copy a user's documents folder to a new hard drive, but when it hits "documents\my music" it says it doesn't have access.

Comment: Doesn't have access on the copy from directory or the copy to directory?

Comment: @tdelaney I guess I'm not sure. It throws a Windows (Error 5 Access is denied)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try using error-catching and or exceptions.

```
except:
  pass
```

Look at this link to find out more on errors an expceptions: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html